# Laravel Ajax Cross Origin Request blocked

Tags: ajax, laravel, cors

I have a weird issue with CORS. **The API and web APP are running on different servers**.

I enabled CORS on the API using [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package, and am trying to consume the API from a different server.

I can consume the API using **Postman** as well as **Guzzle** Http Clients, but it fails when using **Ajax**.

[image: App Request]

When I check the API response; I have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

[image: API Response]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add X-CSRF-TOKEN to the allowedHeaders value in your laravel-cors config. At least that’s what’s indicated by the error message in the question. And based on the request code shows, it looks like you probably need to add Authorization to the allowedHeaders value too.

Comment: did you put this in data ? "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",

Comment: You are able to consume your api from Postman and Guzzle because they make server to server calls.

Comment: @sideshowbarker doesn't "*" allow all headers!

Comment: @adam thats right, but how can I solve this client to server call cors issue?

Comment: I think sidesshowbarker has the right answer. As an alternative, you could make the request to your local server then make the call with guzzle.

Comment: For security, CORS policy does not allow tokens, etc. in calls from the browser because they are exposed. Look into adding the allowed headers and methods that your server CORS is expecting. Check the preflight response int eh Devtools Network tab for clues.

Answer (score -1):

we will get this issue when client and server are on different machines.
Spring by default blocks the request from different host clients by throwing invalid cors request exception.

So you should allow all the origins in server side code.

If you are using spring the below snippet will be helpful.
Add the below code in Spring boot main class or in new configuration file.

```
   @Bean
    public <HttpSecurity> WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("*")
                        .allowedHeaders("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

### In VerifyCsrfToken middleware

`protected $except = [
        'api/*'
    ];`